# What is the connection between "because of the angels" 1 Corinthians 11:10 and Psalm 8:5?

Tags: psalms, 1-corinthians

1 Corinthians 11:1-16 mentions - mankind, glory, honour, angels just as Psalm 8:5 does.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: Actually, Ps 8:5 does not mention angels:  The literal Hebrew is (NASB): Yet You have made him a little lower than God, And You crown him with glory and majesty!  Therefore, I see no connection at all.

Comment: Please could you combine your four answers into one, compiled answer. Thank you. Stack Exchange does allow OPs to answer their own questions. Normally the OP would allow time for other users to state an answer and if none satisfactory were forthcoming the OP would attempt their own. But to answer four times makes it look as though you are wishing to monopolise your own question.

Comment: _... and causest him to lack a little of Godhead ..._ Young's Literal. Psalm 8:5.

Comment: Please quote the verses in full.

Comment: No angles in Ps 8.5 . מאלהים 'from Elohim'

Comment: Bob Jones see my comment below that many NT quotes and references are from the Septuagint or other unknown Greek OT translations  e.g. Hebrews 2:7 quoting the same verse from Psalm 8  v5 "you made him a little lower than the angels" does say angels.

Answer (score 1):

1 Corinthians 11:1-16 is understood by realising that Paul is using Psalm 8 particularly v5   as his template.  Now, it is generally agreed that Ps 8 reflects and expands on Gen 1 showing the order and differentiation of reality with ***God*** (& the spiritual world e.g. angels) **over *Mankind* over *Creation***.   Paul in 1 Cor 11  takes this template and shows that it is equally applicable to the Internal Order of Mankind ie. man and woman as seen in Genesis 2.  So, the template now becomes in 1 Cor 11  ***God* over *Mankind* (*Man* over *Woman*) over *Creation***.    So mankind is seen in completeness of Mankind and in order/differentiation of Man-Woman.   This all parallels what is said in Genesis 1:27 "image of God..... "   ...."him" (Mankind)  "them" (Man-Woman ie. differentiated.

Paul further uses Ps 8:5 to explain how in practical terms man-woman relate such that they are mankind (complete / unity). He does this by taking Ps 8:5 "crowned with glory and honour" - so in 1 Cor 11:7 "woman is the glory of man" or put in another way, man glories in woman AND in 1 Cor 11:3 woman is to honour man. So, the way that mankind wears his crown is by this ordered/differentiated mutual relationship of glory and honour between man and woman.

So where does "because of the angels" fit in to this. Paul has 2 sections to his background theology in 1 Cor 11, namely v7b-9 AND v11-12. V7b-9 are his using Genesis 2 to show the internal workings of mankind in terms of the order of reality seen in Ps 8. And v11 is his once again referring to Ps 8 by noting that Ps 8 only ever mentions "mankind" and does not actually mention "man and woman". So, "because of the angels"is simply a reference back to Ps 8:5 where Mankind is referred to as Mankind and not as man and woman, or woman without man or man without woman ie. just as he says in 1 Cor 11:11 "neither is woman without man, nor man without woman".
Why does he need to refer the reader back to Ps 8 in 1Cor 11:11 if he is already arguing from Ps 8 in 1 Cor 11:7b-9? It is because he has stopped in v10 to apply what he has said in vv7b-9 to the Corinthians ie. the woman need to cover their heads in worship services (ie. at times of prayer and prophesy meetings of the church). "Because of the angels"is him saying he is in v11 restarting the theology based on Ps 8.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please could you edit out the capitals. Many people are offended by this as they see it as 'shouting'. Italics are best for mild emphasis. Bold - only occasionally - for stronger emphasis. Capitals are for genuine, grammatical capitalisation only.

Answer (score 0):

Reply to Dottard.   Not all NT quotations and references are from the Hebrew and particularly the Masoteric Hebrew that we have.  Many are from the Septuagint or unknown Greek translations or are the NT writer translating from an unknown (to us) Hebrew translation.    It is to be noted that elsewhere where the NT quotes Ps 8 it seems to be from the Septuagint or a similar Greek translation known to the NT writer.  This includes Jesus himself in Mat 21:16 where you will find that his words from Psalm 8:2 do not match any Hebrew text that we have, but more closely parallel Greek translations.    It is similar in the book of Hebrews (2:6-8) where the writer quotes Ps 8:4-6  and in fact says  in Hebrews 2:7 "you made him a little lower than the ***angels***".   So, it is very possible that Paul is here referring to Psalm 8:5 "***angels***" as in the Septuagint or a similar Greek translation that he knew.